# Delete last three characters of test in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to delete the last three charecters of the postcode, but the the issue is that the postcode could be eneter the field type is `varchar(max)` any idead how I can't delete the last there characters in the text value.

Currently when I try runing the code I get the follwoing error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Code:

```
SELECT
      c.[postcode],
      left ( ltrim(rTrim(c.[postcode])) ,len(ltrim(rTrim(c.[postcode])))-4) as ode
FROM [testing].[dbo].[canidateinfo] as c
```

Comment: Please read your text.  It does not parse and it has several misspellings.  Can you fix the question?

Comment: Do you consider a space as character? Write output for `'ab'`, `'ab c'`, `'ab c '`, `'ab c d'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will exclude the last 3 characters:

```
SELECT
      c.[postcode],
      ltrim(substring( c.postcode , -2, len(c.postcode))) code
FROM [testing].[dbo].[canidateinfo] as c
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @t table(postcode varchar(20))
INSERT @t values('1234567'),('32'),('abcde'),(' aa123'),('  aa  ')

SELECT 
  postcode, 
  ltrim(substring( postcode , -2, len(postcode))) as code
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
postcode  code
1234567   1234
32        <blank>
abcde     ab
 aa123    aa
  aa      <blank>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the trick:

```
SELECT  LEFT(PostCode, CHARINDEX(' ', Postcode)+1) PostCodeSector
FROM testing.dbo.canidateinfo
```

** Update **

```
CREATE TABLE #postcodeTest (postcode varchar(max))
insert into #postcodeTest
Values
('AB3 4FY'),
('AB34FY'),
('M504FY'),
('M50 4FY')

SELECT  DISTINCT
        CASE (isnumeric(SUBSTRING([Postcode] , 2 , 1))) 
            WHEN 1 THEN LEFT ([Postcode] , 2) 
            ELSE LEFT ([Postcode] , 3) 
        END PcodeArea
FROM    #postcodeTest
```

Comment: using the update, the only selected ab3, M5, which souldnt be the case it should select m50 and leave out 4fy..

Comment: using the update, the only selected ab3, M5, which souldnt be the case it should select m50 and leave out 4fy..

Comment: in the case the poscode willl be b57dr it should only slect b5

Answer (score 0):

If your passed variable is null or less than the 3(because you specified -3 in query), then it will throws error as you got

```
select a.[postcode],
      iif(len(a.[postcode])<3,a.[postcode],left(a.[postcode],len(lTrim(a.[postcode]))-3) as trimmed
FROM [testing].[dbo].[canidateinfo] as a
```

I used iif(exp,true,false) function it will checks for length and works according to it...